# Cypher query migrate from 2nd to 3rd neo4j version

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have app based on neo4j, spring boot, spring data and have to migrate from 2nd to 3rd version of neo4j. Integration test with embedded neo4j failed with very simple query to neo4j , for example

```
MATCH ()-[r0:`ADDRESS_RELATION`]-() RETURN  r0
```

this query work ok with prev version

More complex query, which is generated by spring data,  like this one

```
MATCH ()-[r0:`ADDRESS_RELATION`]-()    
WITH r0,startnode(r0) AS n, endnode(r0) AS m   
MATCH p1 = (n)-[*0..1]-()  
WITH r0, COLLECT(DISTINCT p1) AS startPaths, m 
MATCH p2 = (m)-[*0..1]-()   
WITH r0, startPaths, COLLECT(DISTINCT p2) AS endPaths   
WITH ID(r0) AS rId,startPaths + endPaths  AS paths 
UNWIND paths AS p   
RETURN DISTINCT p, rId")
```

works good.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your first query uses Cypher syntax that is legal in version 3.x. How does the relevant integration test determine "failure"? E.g., is it looking for a specific set of rows in a specific order in the result? In other words, perhaps your integration test is being unreasonably specific?

Comment: Test expect some quantity of relations, which shall be returned by this query. This test and query work as expected with neo2j 2nd version and spring data 3rd version, but failed with neo4j 3rd and SDN 4.x version

Comment: @cybersam is there any official docs for what's changed/broken in Cypher v3 compared to v2? My Google-fu is failing me.

Comment: There are release notes for every release (e.g., [the notes for 3.0.0](https://neo4j.com/release-notes/neo4j-3-0-0/)), but they may not be detailed enough for your purposes.